# Optimisation problem in (mathematical) economics.

Tags: calculus

Define $Q$ to be the level of output produced and sold and assume that the firm's cost function is given by the relationship:

$$TC= 20+5Q+Q^2$$

Furthermore, assume that the demand for the output of the firm is a function of the price $P$ given by the relationship:

$$Q =25-P$$

a. Determine the output level where total profits are maximized.

b. Calculate total profits and selling price at the profit maximizing output level

c. If fixed costs increase from $\$20$ to $\$25$, determine the impact on the profit maximizing output level and total profits.

I solved a,b. ( I calculate selling price is $20$. Please let me know if it's the right answer)
But I don't know how to do c) question. Anybody can show me how to do it please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is it a perfect market?

Comment: The fixed cost is the $20$ part of the $TC$ function. Now change the function for $c$ to conform and redo a,b with that and compare.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you so much! I got my answer ^^